# How do I fix type checker error of imported literal annotation?

Tags: python, annotations, literals, mypy, typechecking

I have a class

```
class Literals:

    runtime_type = Literal["offline", "online"]
```

that contains reusable type hinting literals, that might be used at multiple places in code.

Then, I import `Literals` and use it like this:

```
class FooBar:

   def __init__(runtime_type: Literals.runtime_type) -> None:
       self.runtime_type = runtime_type
```

When I run pyre, I got the following error:

`` Undefined or invalid type [11]: Annotation `Literals.runtime_type` is not defined as a type. ``

Is there any way to work around it? How to make pyre understand that `Literals.runtime_type` is inedeed `Literal["offline", "online"]`?

Answer (score 1):

I tested with `mypy` and this is working, I added `self` to `__init__`:

```
class Literals:
    runtime_type = Literal["offline", "online"]


class FooBar:

    def __init__(self, runtime_type: Literals.runtime_type) -> None:
        self.runtime_type = runtime_type
```

Comment: ok, so it seems that only pyre has issues with this